# Do turns carry over from previous encounters with fleeing Legendary Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I've been trying to catch Thundurus, but I don't know which is the best Poké Ball, the [Quick ball](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Quick_Ball#Quick_Ball) or the [Ultra ball](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ultra_Ball#Ultra_Ball)?

I left the wild Thundurus with 1 hp and asleep, but I don't know if it counts as one turn on the new encounters or if my previous turns carry over. I am using both types of Poké Balls at the moment, and it does not look like any are good. >.<

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite the fact that you may have been pecking away at wandering pokemon for many, many turns, whenever you meet them, it starts a new battle, from turn 1.

This means that the Quick Ball has twice the capture rate (x4) than that of the Ultra Ball (x2).

Comment: Yep, quick balls work (relatively) great for this. The catch rate just seems low because...it's extremely low.

Comment: ty for the quick answer =) i should have save my master ball for him >.< Push me luck =D

Comment: @MichelAyres it might also help to know that status effect change your odds.  I believe it is 2× increase for sleep or freeze, and 1.5× for others.

Comment: @tzenes `Most legendary Pokémon have a catch rate of 3. Assuming its HP is almost depleted and it is paralyzed, and Dusk Ball is used at night or in a cave, then the chance of catching the Pokémon with each ball in Generation IV is approximated by 3 * 3.5 * 1.5 / 255 = 15.75/255 ~ 6.2%, resulting in about 16 Dusk Balls required to catch the Pokémon on average.
If an Ultra Ball were used instead, then the chance drops to 3 * 2 * 1.5 / 255 = 9/255 ~ 3.5%, which amounts to about 28 Ultra Balls on average.` [Bulbepedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Catch_rate#Examples)

Comment: @Michel, yes 1.5 fits for paralyzed